# How does Chromium on linux get auto updated?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome, cron, apt

I often see new features getting added to my chromium browser in Ubuntu 18.04 - without me having run a package upgrade. I also haven't found any  running cron job that upgrades packages.

This what the last modified timestamps look for a few binaries and links.

```
$ ls -l `which chromium-browser `
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 7134 Sep 20 15:05 /usr/bin/chromium-browser

$ ls -l `which ls`
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 133792 Jan 18  2018 /bin/ls

$ ls -l `which soffice `
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Sep 21 17:14 /usr/bin/soffice -> ../lib/libreoffice/program/soffice

$ ls -l `which gimp`
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 Mar 28  2018 /usr/bin/gimp -> gimp-2.8

$ ls -l `which firefox`
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Sep 18 03:57 /usr/bin/firefox -> ../lib/firefox/firefox.sh
```

You'd see the ls binary is quite old and that's what I'd expect it to be. But I'm not sure how / why the other ones are so recently modified.

Any clue would be helpful.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check on your Ubuntu 18.04 if you have installed `unattended-upgrades` package:

```
dpkg -l | grep unattended-upgrades
```

If yes, probably this is the reason of "auto-magic" updates ;)

Comment: Yes I do and this quite surely is the source of the upgrades - checked from log files in /var/log/unattended-upgrades. Thanks!